# Ionic - Passing Data to another page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hello i want to pass the user id (uid) from the home page to a user Details Page. Because i display multiple users on my home page i don’t wan to pass the user session id (as given by the `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));` ),  i want to click on the name of any user on the home page and pass its id and other parameters on the user details page.

home.html
`<p (click)="UserPage()" [innerHTML]="item.username | linky"></p>`

home.ts

```
public userDetails: any;
public resposeData: any;
public dataSet: any;
public noRecords: boolean;
rootPage: any = HomePage;
pages: Array<{ title: string, component: any }>;
userPostData = {
uid: “”,
token: “”,
username: “”,
message: “”,
msg_id: “”,
title: “”,
description: “”,
media_pic: “”,
created:""
};

constructor(
    public common: Common,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public app: App,
    public menu: MenuController,
    public authService: AuthService,
    platform: Platform,
    statusBar: StatusBar,
    splashScreen: SplashScreen,
) {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
    this.userDetails = data.userData;
    this.userPostData.uid = this.userDetails.uid;
    this.userPostData.token = this.userDetails.token;
    this.userPostData.username = this.userDetails.username;
    this.userPostData.msg_id = this.userDetails.msg_id;
    this.userPostData.message = this.userDetails.message;
    this.userPostData.title = this.userDetails.title;
    this.userPostData.description = this.userDetails.description;
    this.userPostData.media_pic = this.userDetails.media_pic;
    this.userPostData.created = this.userDetails.created;
    this.noRecords = false
    this.allArtists();

}

note: this is how i call the users via Auth Service

allArtists() {
this.common.presentLoading();
this.authService.postData(this.userPostData, “newsFeed”).then(

        result => {
            this.resposeData = result;
            if (this.resposeData.friendsNewsFeed) {
                this.common.closeLoading();
                this.dataSet = this.resposeData.friendsNewsFeed;
                console.log(this.dataSet);

            } else {
                console.log("No access");
            }
        },
        err => {
            //Connection failed message
        }
    );
}

UserPage() {
this.navCtrl.push(UserPage, { uid: this.userPostData.uid });
```

userProfile.ts

```
mport { NavController, App, AlertController, MenuController, NavParams } from “ionic-angular”;

export class UserPage {
public uid: string;

constructor(
public common: Common,
public navCtrl: NavController,
public app: App,
public menuCtrl: MenuController,
public navParams: NavParams,
public authService: AuthService
) {
this.uid = navParams.get(‘uid’);

        console.log(this.uid);
    this.userProfile();
}

}
```

auth-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

let apiUrl = "http://localhost/PHP-Slim-Restful1/api/";
//let apiUrl = 'https://api.thewallscript.com/restful/';
/*
  Generated class for the AuthService provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello AuthService Provider');
  }

  postData(credentials, type){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      let headers = new Headers();
      this.http.post(apiUrl+type, JSON.stringify(credentials), {headers: headers}).
      subscribe(res =>{
        resolve(res.json());
      }, (err) =>{
        reject(err);
      });

    });

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With [NavParams](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavParams/), you doing it the right way already.

*It is not visible for me how your `item` structure is.* When you setup your links at your homepage like this: `<p (click)="UserPage()" [innerHTML]="item.username | linky"></p>`, you could pass the user id of this item into the function like this: `UserPage(user.uid)`.

What happens now, is that your `UserPage` function already gets the right uid and can pass it to the detailed view.

Comment: No i am not Stephan. I hope i was I am getting the session user id NOT the id of the i click on. Thanks

Comment: Then pass the session id? I do not understand the problem to be honest.

Comment: If i pass the session id then the UserPage will show the session users Profile Page not the person i clicked for. Sorry i don't know how else to explain it.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am saying! Pass the right id, or both. There is no technical problem.

Comment: Can you post an example code? Console log each id after onclick.

Comment: I do not know your data, so no I can not give you an example. But you doing all right already, just add more data to your `navCtrl.push(UserPage, OBJECT)` object. I really do not get your problem. If you want me to understand your problem, work on your question and your example code, you can still edit it!

Comment: Then why i am getting always the same id on the console the session user id that is, when i click on a user?

Comment: Am i really stuck on something that clear? I mean i click on different users and i am still getting the same id - the user session id

Comment: Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
util.js:60
Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
util.js:60
Array [ {…} ]
app.component.ts:80:20
Array [ {…} ]
app.component.ts:116:20
Array [ {…} ]
app.component.ts:98:20
Array [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
home.ts:98:20
99
home.ts:112:8
99   its the session user id should be 1

Comment: I found where the problem lies @Stephan. I am calling const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData")); that mean i am calling the session user's data right? So when i am calling this.userPostData.uid i am calling the session id right? I found out that i can't use item.uid because i am not returning uid on the PHP function but the user id is uid_fk on that certain table on the database.

Answer (score 0):

OK I got the answer. You need to pass the parameters in the with onclick.

home.html

home.ts

```
UserPage(uid_fk) {
this.navCtrl.push(UserPage, { uid_fk: uid_fk });
console.log(uid_fk);
}
```